# How can I find which applications are installed on my system?

Tags: installed-programs

Is it possible to get a list of the applications which have been installed?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the Ubuntu Software Centre.  Click on the button labelled "Installed".  All the apps installed will be listed under their respective categories.

A command line [alternative](http://iwtf.net/2010/01/05/list-backup-or-restore-installed-packages-on-debian-and-ubuntu/) is to use

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections
```

Answer (score 2):

Just press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows flag key) and goto **application lens** (on the bottom). Click **installed** and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

or by synaptic,

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

[image]

Hope it help.